# How to configure a printer in my Spring boot Angular application or how can i implement printer in Spring-boot Angular application?

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on `spring-boot` with an Angular application. I want to show a list of printers in my page so that I can select one of them and go for the print option. Can you please suggest me how to tackle this task in my project from the server side and also in the UI side.

I am trying to approach the right way for this solution.

Comment: Please provide the code or concepts you tried so far. That will be helpful for getting quick answers.

Comment: @zafrul also be more specific about the list of printers: is it the list of printers connected to your computer, in your local network?

Comment: Yes,all printers are connected with my local computer,in local network